# R Write multiple MannKendall results to data frame or csv

Tags: r

I'm a R beginner, and I'm struggling to find a solution to something that's probably extremely straightforward. Help appreciated.

I'm evaluating sulfate trends in >1,000 groundwater wells using the MannKendall package in R, and I've been storing results as individual lists. I'd like to combine all the results into a single dataframe, so I can target wells with increasing concentrations and export results to CSV and share with folks who don't know how to use R.

```
#Example:
library(Kendall)
w1<-c(4.3,5.7,2.4,9.8,6.7,3.9,8.3,9.6,4.7)
w2<-c(3.2,5.8,9.9,14.6,17.8,13.5,20.4,78.9,50.3)
w1mk<-MannKendall(w1)
w2mk<-MannKendall(w2)

#Next step: combine and store w1mk and w2mk results as data frame for analysis/export
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you would like your data frame to look like, but anyhow check this

```
as.data.frame(rbind(unlist(w1mk),unlist(w2mk)))
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(unlist(w1mk),unlist(w2mk))
```

Comment: Thanks... when I run this on my larger dataset, I get an error that an object cannot be found. Is there a limit to the number of variables you can pass to rbind?

Comment: I guess there is always memory limits, but otherwise no, you can put many variables in rbind. Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I would, but my sloppy code is over the character limit for the original post. If you can imagine the small example above, but with 1,700 wells instead of two, that would be it. I'm using unlist like this: w1mk<-unlist(Mannkendall(w1)), and rbind: trends<-as.data.frame(rbind(w1mk,w2mk)). It seems to work fine with a smaller set of results, but gives an error when I run rbind on all 1,700 trend test results, whether or not they're in list or vector format. It doesn't seem to be a typo...

Comment: how about: bind_rows(unlist(w1mk),unlist(w2mk)) I added it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

@CBernhardt I'd break this down into small manageable steps to see what's going on with your data...

Starting with your example data...

```
library(Kendall)
w1<-c(4.3,5.7,2.4,9.8,6.7,3.9,8.3,9.6,4.7)
w2<-c(3.2,5.8,9.9,14.6,17.8,13.5,20.4,78.9,50.3)
```

First thing I would do is to put all these individual lists into one big dataframe with one site (well) per column

```
groundwater <- data.frame(w1=w1,w2=w2)
groundwater
```

Then use a simple `lapply` command to run the test across each column (well/site)

```
allofthem <- lapply(groundwater, function(y) unlist(MannKendall(y)))
```

`allofthem` is now a list of the Mann Kendall results per site...

```
allofthem

#$w1
#       tau         sl          S          D       varS 
# 0.2222222  0.4655123  8.0000000 36.0000000 92.0000000
```

When you're sure that's working through it all in a dataframe

```
MKResults <- as.data.frame(allofthem)
MKResults
```

Comment: Same number of readings for every site?  Can you flip the spreadsheet the other way?

Comment: You're welcome please feel free to mark the answer is it solved it.